# How to set timeout for gcc compilation of .c file on linux

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I am trying to compile a C code through my php script using gcc on a linux machine. But if the C code contains an infinite loop , the compiler gets stucked.

my PHP script goes like this ..

```
shell_exec('gcc input.c -o output 2> compile.txt');
$output=shell_exec('./output');
```

The 'input.c' file goes like this..

```
#include<stdio.h.
void main()
{
      while(1)
      prinf("This is infinite loop");
}
```

When I compile the PHP code , it gives an

```
**PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 403177472) (tried to allocate 804896768 bytes)**
```

I've tried timeout 5s :
    $output=shell_exec('./output');

but it doesn't work although it works if i do ..

```
 int i;
 while(1)
 {
      scanf("%d",&i);
 }
```

..in my input.c file. I have seached a lot but in vain.. 
What am I doing wrong.?

Comment: Reading your question I see what you are trying to do but I don't understand why. You might try explaining a bit about that, there may be a better way of doing what you want to do. It's hard to say what you're doing wrong without understanding what you're trying to do. Are you trying to use php in place of a makefile?

Comment: Are you looking for a PHP solution for time out or do you want the c program to exit?

Comment: Are you sure an infinite loop in the code would hang the **compiler**?

Comment: There actually *are* buggy programs that will hang GHC, but that's a very different sort of compiler (the authors decided that a certain edge case was too expensive to test for).

Comment: @DavidMason I just want to compile a random c code and produce the output. If the c code has errors , i should be able to display them , and if it has infinite loops (as mentioned) , it should be able to stop exhausting memory and time and display a warning/error msg.

Answer (score 1):

The first point is that, it is not the compiler which is getting stuck. The compiler compiles code fine. It is during execution that your code is going into a infinite loop. So, incase of your first code, it just keeps executing without any pause or exit and hogs the CPU all the time which gives a feeling of "being stuck".

With regard to how your second code works, it is because you are pausing for getting an input. But, again, in that case, you have failed provide an exit for your program. So, effectively, the second code is same as your first code, but it just doesn't hog the CPU.

There is only one way for you to correct this problem, that is by modifying your 'C' code not to have an infinite loop without any exit.

Example:

```
int i;  
while(1)  
{ 
  scanf("%d",&i);  
  if(0 == i) 
  {
    break; //Just an example as to how you can exit from an infinite loop
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your replies @jay..

I know that the infinite loop is a problem but i want to make the compilation good enough to deal with such a type of code.

I'm not controlling the c code, I want to make the compiler deal with it , that's why i want to timeout gcc when such a condition is met or may be memory allocation limit.

Comment: Compiler cannot and does not check your logic. In this case it is problem with logic of your code. So, there is nothing you can do with gcc in this code which can correct the problem.

Comment: There are sites which allow you compile your code , where anyone can post any code. How would they handle such situations.?

Comment: @mayurvir: I imagine most of them use `fork`/`exec` or `popen` (or their PHP equivalents, which i'm too lazy to look up atm) to spawn a child process to run the command.  They then wait for the time limit to expire, at which point they kill the process if it's not already finished.  I imagine they also have resource limits set up in such a way that one program can't use up all the CPU time.

Comment: mayurvir, you keep talking about timing out gcc, but gcc is not in an infinite loop and its compilation halts, so that is not terribly useful. By the way, if you are compiling and running random C code submitted by internet users, you need to be much, much, much more careful about security. At the very least, use chroot and severe restrictions of other sorts. Better, run it in a virtual machine (Xen, Virtualbox, etc.). Best, run it in a whole-machine emulator. Otherwise, you're asking for someone to crack your system but good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ulimit`](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) in the invocation of the program. E.g. the following will limit `output` to 1 second of CPU time:

```
shell_exec("ulimit -t 1; ./output")
```

It might be a good idea to limit other resources too, so that `output` can't use all your memory etc.

(Note that this limits CPU time, not absolute time. If you want to do that, you should look at a program like [`timelimit`](http://devel.ringlet.net/sysutils/timelimit/), which would be called like `shell_exec("timelimit -T 1 ./output")`, I think.)

Answer (score 0):

Jay explains much of it very well. The rest of it is that your first program not only goes into an infinite loop, but also produces an infinite amount of output, all of which you try to store in $output. I'd say you're lucky you didn't crash your computer, but PHP probably saved you with a built-in memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is possible theoretically:

[You can read about the halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

However, you can probably use something like PHP's set_time_limit

Comment: set_time_limit() sets the timelimit of the entire script. Moreover, the problem is when I excute the 'output' file from linux shell (shell_exec)